# node.js-mysql connection failed on windows7

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am just getting started with  nodejs.

My question is that i get an **Error:**

```
connect ECONNREFUSED

npm install mysql;
```

**server.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '3306'
});
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
connection.end();
```

**Finally**

1.I don't know the "**user**" and "**password**";

2."In mysql.conf, comment skip-networking.", I can't find **mysql.conf**;

3.I have tried this and **it's not working**, my platform is **windows 7**.

```
var client = mysql.createClient({
user: uuuu,
password: pppp,
host: '127.0.0.1',
port: '3306',
_socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',});
```

Comment: check with username as "root". Also, is your mysqld running?

Comment: It's not working with username as "root".
mysqld? I do nothing with mysql except "npm install mysql". Thank you

Comment: @Don you are aware that you need to be running the MySQL database server before you can use it from Node, right?

Comment: Your mysqld or mysql deamon is not running. Please install mysql server and try again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear you have not install mysql server in your windows yet. So you should go to http://www.mysql.com and download the server, install and set up, you can set your username and password and grant privilege to it, so you will know the user and password, and mysql.conf will be inside your installation. And if you are in windows, generally you would not use a UNIX socket to build the connection. So "_socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'" should not be here.